# Axapta: How can the Table Name, Not the Table ID, be used as a select in the Select Dialog of the Database Log Report?

Tags: x++, axapta

Currently only the Table Id can be used which is meaningless as it is a number. A little bit of code example would really be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new `RunBaseReport` class and remember to name the `SysDatabaseLog` report in the `lastValueElementName` method.

Prompt the table name in the `dialog` method; use the `TableName` extended data type to enable lookup.

```
Object dialog() 
{
    DialogRunbase dlg = super();
    ;
    dialogTableName = dlg.addFieldValue(typeId(TableName),tableId2Name(tableId));      
    return dlg;  
}
```

Update the table id range of the `queryRun.query()` in the `getFromDialog` method after calling `super()`. Use the `tableName2Id` function to convert to table id.

```
boolean getFromDialog()
{
    boolean ret = super();
    ;
    tableId = tableName2Id(dialogTableName.value());
    this.queryrun().dataSourceNo(1).findRange(fieldNum(SysDatabaseLog,Table)).value(queryValue(tableId));
    return ret;
}
```

In the `validate` method, validate that table name is valid (table id not 0, table not temp etc.).

Lastly you change the output menu item to point to the class rather than the report.

Warning: code has not been tested!

Comment: "Update the table id range of the queryRun.query() in the getFromDialog method after calling super(). Use the tableName2Id function to convert to table id."

I'm a bit stuck with the above - could you clarify a bit more for me? - Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: Thanks a million - I got it working by hacking around a bit with all the help that you provided.